# How to programmatically rotate the view by 180 degrees on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

How to programmatically rotate the view by 180 degrees in my iPhone App?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Should be possible by using [CGAffineTransform](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGAffineTransform)

Quote from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995923/cgaffinetransform-reset/5996285#5996285), this should do the trick:

```
CGFloat radians = atan2f(yourView.transform.b, yourView.transform.a);
CGFloat degrees = radians * (180 / M_PI);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((90 + degrees) * M_PI/180);
yourView.transform = transform;
```

Comment: This rotates it 90 degrees. If you want it to rotate it by 180 degrees, they last line should be `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((` **180** `+ degrees) * M_PI/180)` instead of 90

Answer (score 36):

As ’CGAffineTransformRotate’ uses radians as its unit of measure, and 180 degrees is the same as PI, instead of the math provided in other answers you can simply do:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform, M_PI);
```

**Swift 3:**

```
view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: .pi)
```

If you plan on doing a lot of transforms, it's probably best to read up on radians, so you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 9):

Swift 4:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi);
```

And a COMMENT (I evidently don't have enough points to enter my comment on his/her answer) for **Benjamin Mayo** or **vtcajones** answer of:

```
view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: .pi)
```

This will work the first time, but the next time it is called it will rotate the view again, back to the original rotation, which is probably not what you want.  It would be safer to set the transform value exactly each time.

Answer (score 6):

Simple solution:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees*M_PI/180);
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 3 :

```
let rotationDegrees =  180.0
let rotationAngle = CGFloat(rotationDegrees * M_PI / 180.0)
view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)
```

Answer (score 4):

Same outcome as @Manny's answer using a different function.

```
 CGFloat degreesOfRotation = 180.0;
 view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(view.transform,
     degreesOfRotation * M_PI/180.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Latest Swift 3 syntax:

```
view.transform = view.transform.rotated(by: .pi)
```