# How to rotate view to landscape mode in block-based animation

Tags: iphone, animation, ios4

My application contains a Tab Bar Controller and Navigation controller.
Its totally in Portrait mode. Now I have a table view in 2nd tab, clicking on each row of table view will push another view controller which will show a graphical chart, now I want this chart to be in landscape mode where as the rest of application is in portrait mode.

I came to know that we have to rotate the view on our own, now my question is how to rotate this new view in landscape mode. I put some UIView animations in viewWillAppear function, but I want the block-based animation to rotate this view to landscape for me and when I go back it rotate back portrait mode.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please refer to [Previous Post][1] which may help you to get solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813899/is-it-possible-to-programatically-rotate-the-view-by-180-degrees

Answer (score 1):

Check the device orientation and make the rotation depends on it:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{ myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * 0.5); } ];
```